# Quotient Fields of the Gaussian Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, quotient-group, gaussian-integers

Let $R= \mathbb{Z}[i]$. In my class notes I have that $ R/(1+2i)R $ is either isomoprhic to $  \mathbb{Z}/5$ or $\mathbb{Z}/{5^2}$.

We know that $(1+2i)R$ is a prime ideal, so $R/(1+2i)R$ is an integral domains. The argument seemed to involve the kernel of the map $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R/(1+2i)R$.

The conclusion was that $ R/(1+2i)R \cong \mathbb{Z}/5.$

Similarly, $ R/3R $ was shown to have order 9. This proof seemed to rely on showing that $3R$ is a maximal ideal, which apparently automatically results in $ R/3R $ being a field of order 9.

I'm sorry this question is so vague, I don't understand what the argument was supposed to be.

Comment: Are you familiar with the facts that for commutative rings $R$  with identity one has $R/I$ is an integral domain $\iff$ $I$ is a prime ideal and similarly $R/I$ is a field $\iff$ $I$ is maximal? (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prime_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Integral_Domain) or [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Field) )

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why $R/(1+2i)$ is be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ or  $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$

Comment: $R/(a+bi)$ always has $a^2+b^2$ elements. The question is when it will be an integral domain (a finite integral domain is always a field). For that to happen either $a^2+b^2$ is equal to $2$, a prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$, or $p^2$, $p\equiv3\pmod4$. The proof requires a bit of number theory. Anyway, that is surely the source for "either $p$ or $p^2$".

Comment: Adding a bit more: For any prime $p$ we have that $R/pR$ has $p^2$ elements. The point is that the ideal $p$ is maximal (or prime) if and only if $p\equiv3\pmod4$. When $p=5$ you should be able to see that $(1+2i)R$ is a strictly larger ideal than $5R$. But with $p=3$, $3R$ is actually a maximal ideal.

Comment: One more thing $R/pR$ is never isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/p^2$ because all the elements $x$ of $R/pR$ satisfy $px=0$.